# What tool do I use to remove this wide and flat screw-esque thing?

Tags: light-fixture, fastener, porch

I need access to the wires behind my porch light and need to remove this thing to do it. It's very wide and flat

What tool do I use to remove it?

Edit: it is larger than a quarter.

Also what is it called?

[image: wide and flat fastener in porch light]

Comment: Can't tell scale from the pic but it appears that almost any flat metal blade that fits should enable you to turn it. Appears to be threaded so counter clockwise should do it.

Comment: If you don't have a wide flat object that can fit in there, use some needle-nose pliers and twist.

Comment: Sure but surely there has to be a specific tool to use for this. They didn't just make this and say "well people will figure something out," right?

Comment: Where is this *flush threaded plug" found? You mention a porch light, is this on the back of the light fixture, or what?

Comment: you named the tool in your question ... use a coin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're plastic electrical box knockout plugs and they are included with weatherproof electrical boxes. I've never seen or heard of a tool designed specifically to install/remove them. A large slotted screwdriver is probably the most used item and is what's shown in the box instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try a coin, ( *a quarter* ) or a large washer, hold it in a pair of pliers for leverage.

Or the side of a door key.

Think outside the box, or the slot as it were.

Comment: I was able to get it unscrewed with two screwdrivers pushing in opposite directions but I would still like to know the proper tool for this. A fastener should not exist without a corresponding tool

Comment: @merlinpatt there is always a tool for every situation...

Answer (score 0):

some sort of wide screwdriver:
[image]